# How can I format strings correctly on a new line for every string I receive from a server

Tags: python, sockets, split

So I got a client-server program which encrypts/decrypts strings it receives from a file. The server correctly receives the strings in correct format using .split()

```
#this is correct
Geheime bericht 1
Project PAD
Wachtwoorden
```

When I want to send that data back in .upper() it results this in the 
client instead

```
GEHEIME BERICHT 1PROJECT PADWACHTWOORDEN
```

Using .split() it prints the words on the newline. However the words are not correctly returned. This is the list of the .split()

```
['GEHEIME', 'BERICHT', '1PROJECT', 'PADWACHTWOORDEN']
```

It should be like this(this is how the client first sends it to the server)

```
b'Geheime bericht 1\n'
b'Project PAD\n'
b'Wachtwoorden'
```

using a for loop on the list prints it like

```
GEHEIME
BERICHT
1PROJECT
PADWACHTWOORDEN
```

How am I able to solve this? It seems that the main source of the problem occurs when I'm either sending back the decrypted, all capped strings, or when I'm receiving them on the clientside.

Some client-side code:

```py
connectie = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connectie.connect((ipaddr, portnr))

with open('textinput.txt', 'rb') as inh:
    for lijn in inh:
        enc_data = publickey.encrypt(lijn.strip(), 16)
        print(lijn)
        connectie.send(enc_data[0])#verzend encrypted data
        time.sleep(1)

#ontvang de decrypted data/strings
decrypt_data = connectie.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
```

Some server-side code:

```py
with clientconnectie:
    print("\nConnectie gemaakt met: " + conninfo[0] + ":" + str(conninfo[1]))
    while True:
        enc_data = clientconnectie.recv(2048)
        if not enc_data:
            break
        #print encrypted data zodat je kan zien dat het encrypted is
        #print(enc_data)
        data = privatekey.decrypt(enc_data)#decrypt ontvangen data


        #print("\nSuccesvol ontvangen en decrypt op Server:\n" +str(data.decode('utf-8')))
        #verzend de strings/data in uppercase

        clientconnectie.send(data.upper()) #it seems that the main problem is caused by this line
```

Comment: look up `str.decode(...., "uft-8")` - might help. You got binary strings at your hand.

Comment: `split()`  splits text using "\n", "\t" and space but it also remove these chars from text so you have to add "\n"  when you send it back.

Comment: this line `clientconnectie.send(data.upper())` should throw `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` in case a string data is sent

Comment: maybe you should use `.upper()` on original text - without using `split()` - and send it back. This way it will not remove "\n" from text. Later you can use original text with split() only to display it. OR you may have to split to lines and lines to words to get two-dimensional list `[ ['GEHEIME', 'BERICHT', '1'], [PROJECT', 'PAD'], ['WACHTWOORDEN'] ]` - and now you can see where you have to add "\n"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It says data is an int

Comment: `decrypt_data = connectie.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
print(decrypt_data)` returns `GEHEIME BERICHT 1PROJECT PADWACHTWOORDEN
` is the possible problem here?

Comment: @furas how can I insert a \n? The server returns the 3 strings as 1 whole string..

Comment: Maybe in client you shouldn't use `strip()` which remove "\n" before it sends to server. Or you have to create other method to keep information about "\n" - you could send `"\n"` after every sended line of text. And after recv() you would have to split text before you decrypt it. Or you could send length of single line before you send this line and then receive in `for` loop with `recv(length_of_single_line)` instead of singel `recv(2048)`

Comment: `socket` is low level element which need more work to build something useful. People created different rules to describe how to build message and send in socket - these rules are called "protocols" - like HTTP (hyper text transfer protocol) or FTP (file transfer protocol), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've figured it out by manually inserting '\n' using slices.